# Finding status of data and copying across sheets

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, excel-2007

I am very new to VBA. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks a lot.

Sheet 1 (Data to be copied to Sheet 4)

```
     A       B        C           D
 1  ID    Header 2  Header 3    Orders
 2 5000                      455,476,497
 3 5012                          500
 4 5015                        502,503
```

Sheet 2 (Data)

```
     A         B         C         D ........ Q
1  Orders ID         Header 2   Status   Header 4
2   455                         Closed
3   456                          Open
4   476                         Closed
5   497                         Closed
```

Sheet 3

```
   A    B    C    D
1 455  476  497
2 500
3 502  503
```

Sheet 4 (Output Sheet)

```
     A       B        C           D
 1  ID    Header 2  Header 3    Orders
 2 5000                      455,476,497
 3
```

Task: I need to check the status of the following ids 455, 476 and 497 in sheet 3. If the status of all IDs in a row is closed then copy the whole row from sheet 1 to sheet 4, if not move on to the next line.

```
For a = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For b = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        Cells(1, b).Select

        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Orders").Select            

       (Unsure what to put here)

    Next b
Next a
```

I need more reputation to post images here. So, posting the links
(only 2 allowed )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVXfS.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUhFo.jpg, U0Z7mfm, qWOJ3VM

Comment: Specify the cell where you want to paste the copied values.

Comment: I want to paste the copied cells in Sheet Three from cell A1 with the headers from Sheet 1 as well. It has headers from A1 to Q1.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm bit confused. Can you please paste sample screen prints of your data and expected output. If not explain be a bit more clearly.

Comment: What i understand is, Sheet1 has id's corresponding to values present in sheet2, so ther will be an entry with id as 455 in sheet1, 500..etc, So when ever you see status of all  455,476,497 is closed, you need to copy rows corresponding to 455,476,497(3 rows from sheet1) and paste to sheet3. On same lines if 502 is closed and 503 is open, should skip it Am i right in my understanding?

Comment: I have updated the sheet details. I think you understood what i wanted to do. Check 456,476,497 if all of their status is closed find the original row in sheet 1 and paste it in sheet 4 including the header in sheet 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time and making it very clear, have a clarification, i see 455 is open, but still it is copied to output, is it typo error?

Comment: It shd be 455. typo in sheet 2, 455 status should have been closed and 456 status shd be open. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So if I understood right, the row number `N` in Sheet 3 contains all the order IDs of row `N+1` in Sheet 1? So what you actually have to do is loop through Sheet 3, search for every order ID in that row and check in Sheet 2 if it is closed. If all are, then copy the corresponding row of Sheet 1 to Sheet4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```
Sub FindStausAndCopy()

Dim sheet1Range As Range
Dim sheet2Range As Range
Dim sheet3Range As Range

Dim sheet1RowCount As Integer
Dim sheet1ColCount As Integer

Dim sheet2RowCount As Integer
Dim sheet2ColCount As Integer

Dim sheet3RowCount As Integer
Dim sheet3ColCount As Integer

Dim shtRowNum As Integer
Dim totalCellsinRow  As Integer
Dim statusCount As Integer
Dim orders As String

Dim range1Row As Variant
Dim range2Row As Variant
Dim range3Row As Variant
Dim cellVal As Variant



sheet1RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
sheet1ColCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Count

sheet2RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
sheet2ColCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns.Count

sheet3RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count
sheet3ColCount = Worksheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Columns.Count

Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
Set sheet1Range = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(sheet1RowCount, sheet1ColCount))
Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
Set sheet2Range = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(sheet2RowCount, sheet2ColCount))
Worksheets("sheet3").Activate
Set sheet3Range = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(sheet3RowCount, sheet3ColCount))

shtRowNum = 1 'This is for incrementing the Row in Sheet4
'Iterating through Each row in Sheet3 and then through
'each cell in a particular row
'Loop1
For Each range3Row In sheet3Range.Rows
totalCellsinRow = 0  ' to count no of order numbers in sheet3 rows
statusCount = 0      ' to count the status of orders 
orders = ""          ' to store all order numbers with coma seperated

    'Iterating throgh each Order in a row and identifing the status
    'Loop2
    For Each cellVal In range3Row.Cells
    If (cellVal <> "") Then
     totalCellsinRow = totalCellsinRow + 1 'Increments for every order
     'Iterating through each row in sheet2 to check the status and
     ' Increment status count
     'Loop3
         For Each range2Row In sheet2Range.Rows
            If (range2Row.Cells(1) = cellVal And range2Row.Cells(4) = "Closed") Then
            statusCount = statusCount + 1 'Increments only when order is closed
            orders = orders & ", " & cellVal
            End If
        Next range2Row
        'By the time Loop3 is completed we get the status of one order
        End If
    Next cellVal
    'By the time Loop2 is completed, we get the overall status of all orders
    ' in a row of sheet3
    ' If statusCount = totalCellsinRow which implies every order
    ' present in a row is closed
    If (totalCellsinRow = statusCount) Then
        'Lopp4: Iterating throgh each row of sheet1 to find Matching ID
        'The reason for iterating through rows,even if the order of the ID
        ' changes, code should be in a position to identify the right row
        ' to copy
        For Each range1Row In sheet1Range.Rows
            If (range1Row.Cells(4) = Trim(Right(orders, Len(orders) - 1))) Then
              If (shtRowNum = 1) Then
              'Copying the Header row to sheet4 only once.
              sheet1Range.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("sheet4").Cells(1, 1) 
              shtRowNum = shtRowNum + 1
            End If
            'Copying the row from sheet1 to sheet4
            range1Row.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(shtRowNum, 1)
            shtRowNum = shtRowNum + 1
          End If
        Next range1Row
        'By the time Loop4 is completed a ID row for the closed Orders will 
        ' be copied to Sheet4
    End If
Next range3Row
'By the time Loop1 is completed all the orders status will be read
' Corresponding Id rows will be copied to sheet4 with Header row

End Sub
```

Below are the results
[image]

Comment: You could break the loop through the elements in `sheet2Range.Rows` if the element is found. Also you don't have to loop through Sheet1, simply take the row on line N+1, if you found it on row N in Sheet 3.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! :) I will try it out.

Comment: Hi Siva, When I try to integrate it into my sheet i experience some errors. Can u explain how ur code works from the ShtRowNum = 1 ? I already edited my code accordingly.

Comment: @Manick9, I have added my comments in the code. Hope i made my self clear, please let me know if you any thing is not clear. If possible, share your entire code in Question, we can fix the issues and make it work.

Comment: I have uploaded the links. Pls advise how to fix the issue. I think it is because assigned_tasks is empty.

Comment: Please let me know which line of the code is throwing the error?

Comment: Line 96. Do you want me to upload the macro file?

Comment: Sorry, can you please specify the code, i'm not able to figure out the lines from images. If you can upload the code file.

Comment: I guess you are right, for some of your data, `analysis_tasks` is empty string, so its throwing error, what you can do is add one more condition, change `If (totalCellsinRow_2 = statusCount_2)` to `If ((totalCellsinRow_2 = statusCount_2) And totalCellsinRow_2 <>0 )` and try, i guess that should work

Comment: @Siva  Need your help. My data for the first three sheets come from 3 separate workbooks. i need to clear the first 3 sheets and import data everyday. 

My source filename is in this format (filename_ddmm) daily_1908, event_1908, exp_1908. I tried storing the date in custom format but cant drop the year. 2nd issue is when i try to copy i get an error cos the data size is too big. How do u overcome this errors?

Comment: I didn't understand your first issue. Regarding Issue2, if you are trying to copy entire sheet data from source to destination, then i would suggest simply copy sheet from source to destination and delete your old sheet in destination. Other case if you are copying only some portion of data from source sheet to destination, probably have to look for a solution.

Comment: I tried running your code, i don't see any issues here, except Clipboard message. You can skip those messages by adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before `Wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False`and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after it. This will stop all popup display.